# How to preprocess data for keras MobileNetV2?

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, image-classification

Trying out first CNN. I have got a dataframe with links to images. As I understand - I don't need to download them on my machine, I just need to load in in RAM for training the model, so I did this:

```
def preprocess_image(URL):
    response = requests.get(URL)
    image_bytes = BytesIO(response.content)

    img = PIL.Image.open(image_bytes).resize((224,224))
    img_array = img_to_array(img)
    img_array_expended_dims = np.expand_dims(img_array, axis=0)
    return tf.keras.applications.mobilenet_v2.preprocess_input(img_array_expended_dims)

train_batch = df_links[:200].apply(lambda row: preprocess_image(row[0]), axis=1)
```

After that I tried to download and compile a model:

```
mobile_net = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2()
mobile_net.compile(
optimizer='Adam', loss='categorical_crossentripy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

And finally tried to fit:

```
mobile_net.fit(x=train_batch, validation_data=valid_batch, epochs=10, verbose=2)
```

Got this issue:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-121-03a9d117ab58> in <module>
----> 1 mobile_net.fit(x=train_batch, validation_data=valid_batch, epochs=10, verbose=2)

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1041               (x, y, sample_weight), validation_split=validation_split))
   1042 
-> 1043     if validation_data:
   1044       val_x, val_y, val_sample_weight = (
   1045           data_adapter.unpack_x_y_sample_weight(validation_data))

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
   1328     def __nonzero__(self):
   1329         raise ValueError(
-> 1330             f"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. "
   1331             "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
   1332         )

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I got a little bit lost, can't understand how to preprocess data for MobileNetV2. Appreciate any help.

P.S. I've tried another function and that didn't work either:

```
train_batches = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=tf.keras.applications.mobilenet_v2.preprocess_input).flow_from_dataframe(df_links, x_col=0, y_col='y', class_mode='binary')
```

Output:

```
Found 0 validated image filenames belonging to 0 classes.
```

Comment: could you add the full error trace?

Comment: @ÁngelIgualada, thanks, added